# History API, refresh and bookmark

Tags: javascript, refresh, history, bookmarks, pushstate

`pushState` doesn't make a request, it just changes the url and stores a new history entry. Thinking about this concept, it's impossible to refresh or bookmark because the server will always do a request. A server-side solution is needed.
     After several hours searching, I have found a solution, every single call must be redirect to `index.php` to let PHP handle the request.

```
rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 last
```

I don't know exactly how this file should be to let a website refresh or bookmark a page. Can somebody help me ? I made an example to help clarify.

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">

        <title>History API</title>

        <script>
            function ajax (url, callback) {
                var conection = new XMLHttpRequest ();

                conection.open ("GET", url, true);

                conection.setRequestHeader ("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

                conection.send (null);

                conection.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (conection.readyState === 4) {
                        if (conection.status === 200) {
                            callback (conection.responseText);
                        }
                        else if (conection.status === 404) {
                            alert ("Page not found !");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert ("Error !");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            window.addEventListener ("popstate", function (event) {
                var state = event.state;

                if (state) {
                    document.getElementById ("content").innerHTML = state["content"];
                }
            });

            document.addEventListener ("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
                var content = document.getElementById ("content");
                var menu = document.getElementById ("menu");

                menu.addEventListener ("click", function (event) {
                    var target = event.target;

                    if (target.nodeName === "A") {
                        ajax (target.href, function (result) {
                            history.pushState ({"content": result}, target.innerHTML, target.href);

                            content.innerHTML = result;
                        });

                        event.preventDefault ();
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style>
            body {
                width: 400px;
            }

            div {
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id = "menu">
            <a href = "page1.html">Page 1</a>
            <a href = "page2.html">Page 2</a>
        </div>

        <div id = "content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
    isset ($_GET["page"]) or exit ("Error !");

    $page = $_GET["page"];

    // Ajax request
    if (isset ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) && strtolower ($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) === "xmlhttprequest") {
        if (file_exists ($page)) {
            require_once ($page);
        }
        else {
            header ("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
        }
    }
    else {
        require_once ("index.html");
    }
?>
```

**page1.html**

> Hello, I'm the Page 1. It's nice to meet you.

**page2.html**

> Hi brother. I'm page 2.

---

**Clicking (ok)**

[image]

**Refresh (fails)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should really not use a GET parameter as input for a _require_once_. Really. Not. Use at least a simple whitelist of allowed names for pages and only include and output mapped files (or files with those whitelisted names).

Now to your history API problem. Pushing things obviously seems to work for you so all that is missing is probably a simple ondomready event that reads the current URL and loads the content via AJAX or from existing history entries. The same whitelist approach should be used there. Also try to not fall into the trap of DOMXSS by using unvalidated input (the URL) as input for your javascript and DOM operations.

Comment: You said important things about security, thank you. As soon as possible I will take care of them.

Comment: Hey man ! Your answer really helped me, my problem is solved. Thanks !